# how to display "Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View" in custom WP_List_Table column?

Tags: admin, columns, screen-columns

I have removed "Post Title" in admin column, and created a custom column.

Is there any way to the display "Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View" link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those links are hard-coded to display in the "title" column as part of [class-wp-posts-list-table.php](https://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php). Look at the `single_row()` method in that file, specifically the `case 'title'` to see how those links are constructed. You can probably re-use the same code in your plugin or theme as long as you comply with the GPL license WordPress uses.

Comment: Do it work at Custom post? In other words, can i use this method in custom post?

Comment: You'll have to past the code in where you're rendering your custom column, and you'll definitely have to tweak it to use your custom post type. But unfortunately this is one of those times when the WordPress admin code is old, complicated, and not built to be re-used. :(

Comment: tanks my friend :)